# Subpages without _index.md file

Tags: hugo

I don't want to display the list page for the about. `localhost/about` should not even exist. Ideally I would like to not have an `_index.md` file but Hugo complains if I don't have one.

> Content directory "/work/content/about" have both index.* and _index.* files, pick one.

> .File.Dir on zero object. Wrap it in if or with: {{ with .File }}{{ .Dir }}{{ end }}

I am trying to have the following hierarchy

```
content
-- about
   -- use-cases
        _index.md
        --some-use-case
          index.md
   -- faq
      index.md
```

I should be able to access `localhost/about/use-cases` or `localhost/about/faq` but not the `localhost/about`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's more than one way to do this, but the [v0.65.0](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases/tag/v0.65.0)+ way is to use Hugo's
[Build Options](https://gohugo.io/content-management/build-options/). Here's how I do it: First add the `about/_index.md` that the arrow points to below so your directory structure looks like this:

```
content
-- about
     _index.md  <-- discussed below!
   -- use-cases
        _index.md
        --some-use-case
          index.md
   -- faq
      index.md
```

In this `about/_index.md` file put the following front matter.

```
---
cascade:
  _build:
    render: always
    list: always

_build:
  render: never
  list: never
---
```

This is enough to make `localhost/about/` not exist and the content below it exist (that's what the `cascade` part does). If you want to redirect it somewhere you can include the following in the front matter of the page that you want to redirect it to:

```
---
aliases:
  - /about/
---
```

For example, if you want to redirect it to your home page, put the above `aliases` list in `content/_index.md`.

```
content
  _index.md  <-- home page metadata & content!
-- about
     _index.md
⋮
```

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks! Is there a way to return a 404 page when trying to access that page? At the moment it's simply blank. What I am trying to achieve is show a not found there.